# How to destroy all webviews in RecyclerView?

Tags: audio, webview, android-webview, android-recyclerview

I have 5 audio which i pass in adapter and in onbind i load that url in webview, when i press the back button the audio not stoped, i destry the webview but it work on the last webview item position..

I have list of **5 sound cloud embedded url** which i pass in *adapter*.

```
meditationFavSCAdapter = new MeditationFavSCAdapter(FavMeditationActivity.this, favMeditationList, this);
recyclerMeditationfav.setAdapter(meditationFavSCAdapter);

if(favMeditationList.size() > 0) {
  for(int i=0;i<favMeditationAPI.getData().size();i++) {
        favMeditationList.add(favMeditationAPI.getData().get(i));
  }
}
meditationFavSCAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In recyclerview item i declare webview(xml item). And in Onbind method i load that url in webview.

```
videoWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
videoWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT );
videoWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
videoWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
videoWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36");
//Load Url
videoWebView.loadData(favMeditationList.get(position).getEmbedCode(), "text/html" , "utf-8" );
```

**For Destroy Webview**

```
public void destroyWebView() {
        if(videoWebView != null) {
            videoWebView.loadUrl("");
            videoWebView.loadData("", "text/html" , "utf-8" );
            videoWebView.clearHistory();

            // NOTE: clears RAM cache, if you pass true, it will also clear the disk cache.
            // Probably not a great idea to pass true if you have other WebViews still alive.
            videoWebView.clearCache(true);

            // Loading a blank page is optional, but will ensure that the WebView isn't doing anything when you destroy it.
            videoWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");

            videoWebView.onPause();
            videoWebView.removeAllViews();

            videoWebView.destroy();

            // Null out the reference so that you don't end up re-using it.
            videoWebView = null;
        }
    }
```

I call this function when user press Back Button

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        meditationFavSCAdapter.destroyWebView();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

But this code destroy the last webview in the recycler.
So when i play the first webview audio and press back button the audio still play in background whereas when i play the last audio (webview) it stop when backpressed is called.
So i need to destroy all webview in recyclerview.
But i don't know how...